# RoR e-commerce product description not activating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bluecloth

new to ROR ecommerce and am having trouble activating a product.  I have entered a description which saves and appears in the overview and input box but not in the preview in the description editor.  When I go to activate the product I get the flash error: "Please add a description before Activating."  My description still appears in the input box but not below it in the preview.

from product_controller:

```
def activate
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.deleted_at = nil
  if @product.save
    redirect_to admin_merchandise_product_url(@product)
  else
    flash[:alert] = "Please add a description before Activating."
    redirect_to edit_admin_merchandise_products_description_url(@product)
  end
end
```

from product model:

```
before_save :create_content
...
validates :description_markup,presence: true, length: { maximum: 2255 }, if: :active
...

def create_content 
  self.description = BlueCloth.new(self.description_markup).to_html unless self.description_markup.blank?
end
```

ruby -v 2.0.0p247

rails -v 4.0.2

bluecloth 2.2.0

the only gem I added was therubyracer

Thank you for reading my post.

Comment: @product.save returns false, which means there were some errors. Easiest way to see them is to use `@product.save!` - the save! method will raise exception and you will be able to see the problem

Comment: Need to know more details before we could provide an answer I'm afraid

Comment: Thank You lobanovadik! with save!, ror-ecommerce gave me a nice explaination of why the product would not activate.  It was not the description which it had said it was previously, but rather I needed to update inventory/ could not activate a product not in stock.

Comment: I know I'm late but was the error message not showing in the UI?  If not I'll try to update